# Get subgrid data by row id jqgrid

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

We use jqgrid in our website to show data and subdata.

once a row is clicked then we show sub data (if exists) (for that we call server for that data).

After sub data loaded, if the user clicks on the same row then it collapsed.

In a loop for all row,
i want to fetch all subgrid data by row id without expand.(which is loaded once)
Can it possible?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please include in all questions about jqGrid **the version**, which you use (can use), and **the fork** of jqGrid ([free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid), commercial [Guriddo jqGrid JS](http://guriddo.net/?page_id=103334) or an old jqGrid in version <=4.7). You should include **JavaScript code**, which you use to create jqGrid with subgrids. It's possible to load the data in subgrid in different ways. One way will be to load the subgrid on demand only by opening the grid. On collapsing the data could be deleted depend on the options, which you use.

Comment: Alternatively you can load full information about the grid and all subgrids **at once**. The data could be saved in the options of jqGrid and fetching the data will be very easy.